# Is there a way to declare a pointer to a particular method only?

Tags: c++, pointers, pointer-to-member

I have a class:

```
class Car
{
    public:
        Car();
        ~Car();
        // nr indicates which particular door.
        void startEngie();
        void openDoor(int nr);
        void closeDoor(int nr); 
        void openWindow(int nr);
        void closeWindow(int nr);
        void turnOnAirConditioner(int vloume);
}
```

Now by `void (Car::*action)(int)` I declare a pointer named `action` to `Car` method. The problem is that many methods can be assigned to it: `&Car::openDoor`, `&Car::closeDoor`, `&Car::openWindow`, `&Car::closeWindow`, `&Car::turnOnAirConditioner`, but not `&Car::startEngie`.

I wonder if I am right: there is no way to declare a pointer to a particular method only. In other words: `pointer type`, which accept only a particular named function, can't be declared.

Comment: A pointer type that can only have one specific value (two if you count null) doesn’t seem very useful. What’s your use case?

Comment: if you want to point only to one specific method, why dont you use the method itself instead of a pointer?

Comment: It's a bit like wanting a pointer that can only point to the number 5. Why would you need such a thing? Just use 5.

Comment: @molbdnilo Use case isn't important. You're right, this kind of pointer wouldn't be useful. It's just purely academic reasoning. I'm lenring QT5 and `static_cast<void(QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::activated)` came up, and just wondering.

Comment: Objects which contain specific values which should not be changed are commonly called "constants" ;-). @n.m. The use case you describe is not uncommon; you may have encountered a `const int` now and then, and will remember with a bit of nudging why it is preferable to a literal `5`;-). The same reasoning can be applied to function pointers, member functions or not. So the answer to the OP is "yes, of course you can, just make the pointer `const`". (Disclaimer: I have never done that but suppose it works for member function pointers.)-- P.S. Marek's better alternatives notwithstanding.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider a type that can only hold one value is not the same as a variable that is `const`, just saying...

Comment: Possibly add enum/type `EDoorId`, then signature is `void (Car::*action)(EDoorId)`.

Comment: @user463035818 I always thought that the way to declare that "a type [...] can only hold one value" is **exactly** decorating it with `const`. `const`ness is a property of the type; sometimes the language converts between (non-)const types for you; sometimes it doesn't, and you have to cast explicitly. What else would you suggest to express the fact in the type system that an object of that type can only hold a specific value?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider  "constnees is a property of the type". I never thought about it that way and I am not sure if I do agree. Anyhow, there is a difference between `struct Foo { const int x = 5; }; Foo f;` and `const int x = 5;`. Nevermind, I think we are going offtopic ;)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider `const` lets you create *objects* that can only have one value. There's nothing about `const` that limits the potential value an object can have. OP wants a *type* that can only hold one predetermined specific value, not an immutable but arbitrary one.

Comment: @molbdnilo Well, he asked "I wonder if I am right: there is no way to declare a pointer to a particular method only." The answer is yes, there is: a const pointer.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Read the next sentence, too. OP asks for a *type* that can only accept one particular function. That is, a type `T` such that `const T x = &Car::openDoor;` is fine, but `const T x = &Car::closeDoor;` is a type error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't define a type that *is* just "one specific value of this other type", for instance a type whose only existing value is exactly `&Car::closeDoor`.

One thing you *can* do is reach for the Swiss army knife of programming - introduce a level of indirection - and define a type that *represents* one specific value by wrapping it inside something else.

```
// Simplified Car
class Car
{
public:
    void openDoor(int i) { std::cout << "open door\n"; }
    void closeWindow(int i) { std:cout << "close window\n"; }
};

using Fun = void (Car::*)(int);

// A template for an immutable structure, so it 
// can hold only one specific value; the template argument.
template<Fun fun>
struct CarOperation
{
    const Fun f = fun;
};

// Now we can make one type for each operation
using OpenDoor = CarOperation<&Car::openDoor>;
using CloseWindow = CarOperation<&Car::closeWindow>;

int main()
{
    Car c;
    OpenDoor d;
    (c.*d.f)(1);
    CloseWindow e;
    (c.*e.f)(2);
}
```

The syntax is slightly unfortunate, because apparently the `.*` operator doesn't do any implicit conversion of its right operand.

Of course, this is just a very roundabout and obfuscated way of simply calling the function indicated by the type.

It would be more useful with a type that can hold a predetermined subset of the functions (like, say, `DoorOperation` or `Opener` types).
You can probably build that using clever template programming, but I'm not a clever template programmer.

Comment: Re "You can't define a type that is just "one specific value of this other type": That appears patently wrong to me -- that's what `const` types are for. The level of indirection via the `CarOperation` template is therefore unneeded, isn't it? What's the advantage over directly using const member function pointers (as in my example ;-) )?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Yes, it's pretty much as pointless as the question, of academic interest only. The advantage over you answer is that this one attempts to solve OP's problem of creating a *type* that can hold only one specific, predetermined value, while yours solves the problem of storing an arbitrary but immutable value. (Which is not what OP is asking for.)

Comment: I see your point now -- even though `CarOperation` works with any of the functions it's determined at compile time and a property of the instantiated type. One consequence is that different `CarOperation`s  are not assignable or initializable unless they point to the same function anyway. Interesting.

Comment: Although I gave this +1, the statement 'You can't define a type that is just "one specific value of this other type"' is somewhat misleading, given that's exactly what you then do. (It's also the same thing that `std::integral_constant` does)

Comment: @Caleth I see this as a typed wrapper around that value, not as the value itself. That is, it contains the value, but it isn't the value. I updated the wording a bit in an attempt to make it clearer.

Comment: @molbdnilo Now when I have more time. I changed answer, yours seem to me more accurately. You give me exactly what I wanted: `type` for one particular method.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of pointers `void (Car::*action)(int)` are rarely used.
Nowadays there are three preferred ways to approach this:

- template parameter (STL algorithms for example)
- interface (pure abstract class)
- `std::function<void()>` and or lambdas

Apparently you need second solution:

```
class IWindowOpenable {
public:
    virtual ~IWindowOpenable() {}

    virtual void openWindow(int nr) = 0;
};

class Car : public IWindowOpenable
{
public:
    Car();
    ~Car();

    void startEngie();
    void openDoor(int nr);
    void closeDoor(int nr); 
    void openWindow(int nr);
    void closeWindow(int nr);
    void turnOnAirConditioner(int vloume);
};

Car car;
IWindowOpenable *windowOpener = &Car;
```

Note that anything what is implementing interface `IWindowOpenable` can operate only on method with name `openWindow`.
This pointer can point to any typo of object which is implementing this interface.

Comment: inheriting from an interface is not really an alternative to a member function pointer. Inheritance is invasive, member function pointers are not

Comment: Yes but he wrote: `I wondering if I'm right: there isn't a way to declare pointer to particular method only.` and this is a best solution for it. Note I'm taking a correction for newbie, who often do not know how to ask a good question or describe problem well.

Comment: ok, I think I got it, you are saying that you can have a pointer to an instance that has only one specifc method.

Comment: Of course, `static_cast<Car*>(windowOpener)->openDoor()` will still open the door. The third solution (`std::function`) is more robust in that respect, but you need to show how that's initialized (bind/lambda)

Comment: @MSalters but this won't be a OOP anymore. And you have to be sure that `windowOpener` is pointing to a `Car` (it doesn't have to).

Comment: Okay, I understand your solution. If it wouldn't be just wondering but  
necessity for real implementation your answer will work. Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 1):

In comments you said you're asking a purely academic question, so let me give a purely academic answer. You can't have a pointer to only one method, because all these methods have the same type. What you can do is to make them have different types:

```
struct Car
{
    struct open_door_tag { };
    struct close_door_tag { };

    void open_left_door(int nr, open_door_tag = {});
    void open_right_door(int nr, open_door_tag = {});
    void close_door(int nr, close_door_tag = {});
};
```

Now if you have a pointer

```
void (Car::*open_that_door_ptr)(int, Car::open_door_tag);
```

you have some restrictions for assignment:

```
open_that_door_ptr = &Car::open_left_door;   // OK
open_that_door_ptr = &Car::open_right_door;  // OK
//open_that_door_ptr = &Car::close_door;     // Won't compile
```

Unfortunately (or not), you can't call a method through this pointer without providing a tag:

```
Car car;
(car.*open_that_door_ptr)(2, Car::open_door_tag{});
// or (thanks, @Jarod42)
(car.*open_that_door_ptr)(2, {});
// (car.*open_that_door_ptr)(2);     // Won't compile
```

**Note.** After I posted this answer I saw a comment by @Jarod42, who suggested to do essentially the same thing.

Comment: You could bind an `open_door_tag{ }`, although the bind result won't be a member function pointer anymore.

Comment: I satisfied with your answer. To sum up: being very precisely you can't create this kind of 'pointer type' (type word is key), becouse to 'pointer to function' you can assign functions with matched signatures. However you can simulate this kind of behavior. By difference signatures as you showed. Or created const pointer `void(QSpinBox::* const action)(int)` which will force you to initialize on declaration, hence will points to particular function.

Comment: @Jarod42, nice observation. Thanks.

Comment: @SonnyD, I think that `const`ness of a pointer addresses a different issue: you still can assign something meaningless to it upon its construction.

Answer (score 1):

Marek's correct advice to consider using more C++-idiomatic alternatives notwithstanding, your wish is reasonable and can be granted with a simple `const`.

The reason one might want to do that is the same as with all other const definitions (which all could principally be replaced by the right side of their definition): One wants to have a symbolic name so that the meaning of the specific value is understandable in the context of its use, and one wants to have a single point of maintenance in case one wants to change the `const` value. That's why everybody frowns at integer literals in code.

These exact reasons apply to the definition of `const int`s and `void (Car::*const action)(int)`s alike.

So if, to give a contrived example, you want a function which is called every time the car is started, as a non-mutable property of that specific car, you could declare an `atStart` constant member function pointer as a member (I introduced a typedef as well). The pointer must be initialized in the car's constructor, as all const members must.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Car
{
        typedef void (Car::* const CarfuncT)(void);
        Car(CarfuncT atStartArg)
            : atStart(atStartArg) 
        {}
        void startEngine() { cout << "Start Engine\n"; (this->*atStart)(); };
        void turnOnAC() { cout << "AC on\n"; }
        void turnOnHeat() { cout << "Heat on\n"; }
        void turnOnRadio() { cout << "Radio on\n"; }
        void (Car::* const atStart)();
};
```

User code could look like this:

```
int main()
{
  cout << "I'll create a configured car. In which state do you live?\n";

  string state;
  cin >> state;
  Car *car = new Car(state == "Texas" ? &Car::turnOnAC : &Car::turnOnRadio);

  car->startEngine();

  delete car;
}
```